# I install download and install ASP.NET Core 3.1 application SDK, but when i run dotnet --list-sdks I only get 3.0, 6.0 and 7.0

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to run a Dot Net solution, and  I get an NETSDK1045 error saying I need Net Core 3.1.

I download an install Net Core 3.1 SDK, but when I check for installed SDK versions I see Net Core 3.0. Thus I get the same error again when I try to compile the solution.

I go to this link to download Net Core 3.1 SDK

`https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-3.1.32-windows-x64-installer`

I run
`dotnet --list-sdks` to check that 3.1 SDK is installed.

This is the output of `dotnet --list-sdks`
3.0.103 6.0.407 7.0.202

**How come I get 3.0 version when I installed 3.1 ?**

I also tied "<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>" on the cproj file but then I get another error message "System.IO.Hashing doesn't support netcoreapp3.0. Consider updating your TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 or later."

This projects runs with no issues on other machines.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: The link you posted is for the .NET Core 3.1 **runtime**, not the SDK. The 3.1 SDK (Win32, x64) is here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-3.1.426-windows-x64-installer

Comment: Many thanks! No it compiles and runs ok.